# maintenance of steady flow through pressure or mass flow

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, pressure, valves

let's say I have two points in a line, A and B. Between them there is a valve that can regulate the amount of the stream from A to B. Considering that there is a steady flow of the stream between A and B, and is to be always maintained. Is it better to regulate the valve in accordance to the pressure or with the mass flow? what is the difference of using pressure regulator instead of the mass flow meter if the aim is only to maintain the pre-set steady flow?

Comment: I guess it depends what you want to regulate: if you want to regulate the pressure at B, then use a pressure regulator. If you want to regulate the flow rate from A to B, use a mass flow controller.

Comment: @am304 can't we already regulate the pressure inherently with the mass flow control? it will be after all always the same mass flow will correspond to the same pressure level.